# Drupal 7: User warning: The following module is missing from the file system

Tags: drupal-7

I install Drupal 7, but, an error messages displays:

```
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: ajaxblocks. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: menu_clone. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: prestashop_blog_feed. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: ps_search. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: ps_showcases_screenshots. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: ps_wp_fix_date. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: ps_youtube_filter. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: rabbit_hole. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: rh_file. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: rh_node. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: rh_taxonomy. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: rh_user. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: publication_date. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1138 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/bootstrap.inc).
Notice: Use of undefined constant _IPB_COOKIE_PREFIX_ - assumed '_IPB_COOKIE_PREFIX_' in IPBUser::fetchMemberData() (line 10 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/sites/all/modules/custom/ps_sso_ipb/class/IPBUser.php).
Error: Call to undefined function menu_clone_load() in _menu_load_objects() (line 603 of /projet/site-prestashop-tma/includes/menu.inc).
```

I read  the documentation but I don't understand it.

Comment: You can check this page for complete details https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215

Comment: Are you able to use drush. If you can try running drush dre <module_name>

Answer (score 1):

The [missing module](https://www.drupal.org/project/missing_module) can come in handy.

If you're into [drush](http://drush.org):

```
drush en -y missing_module
drush lmm  # list missing modules
drush rmm  # remove missing modules
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. This worked for me.

Comment: Yeah the question should be moved over to drupal.stackexchange.com, where it can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can fix these errors.

1. Place the modules back to the location and login via superadmin and disable and uninstall each one of them.

OR (2nd way needs proper backup and mysql knowledge)

2. Update system table ( delete all the rows containing the module list you have warnings for like ajaxblocks, menu_clone etc). This must be done after taking proper backup of your database / site.

Your query will somewhat in this format

```
DELETE FROM system WHERE name like "ajaxblocks" or name like "menu_clone";
```

The or conditions can be many based on the list of modules which you are getting warning for.

Comment: 2. doesn't work

Comment: After deleting from system table you need to clear all cache.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with a site, and I look on the DB inside the system table the route of module.
Because you can find the folder module inside two routes
/module
/sites/all/modules/

Then you look the .module file, and in my case the file extension was .modul, I change the extension and it works for me.